# netdom join switch lowercase hostname to uppercase

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

When I join some pc to domain the hostname of the PC switching to uppercase. Since we have mixed ( linux/windows ) environment this provide us some issues.

How can I join the PC with lowercase hostname to domain via netdom command and leave lowercase hostname on it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The NetBIOS hostname has always been uppercase. The host name in the DNS server is likely not uppercase.

Comment: I need to disable convert the hostname to upper case whle joining domain. 
Before I join domain - the hostname  was lowercases.

Comment: From the additional checking I found that this is windowns server 2012 behavior: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1dd1bbae-0ff5-412b-8d5a-d0ac09a40a79/why-windows-server-2012-tends-to-change-computer-name-to-uppercase-?forum=winserver8gen